# Sonarqube failing to start even after clearing the $SONAR_HOME/data/es folders

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

I am getting the below error message in the sonarqube logs and sonarqube web page is not accessible. I found out the solution that clearing the $SONAR_HOME/data/es/ would fix it. But it didn't. Please let me know if there are any other alternative ways.

```
2017.11.30 08:58:51 WARN   es[o.e.index.engine]  [sonar-1511055210245] [tests][2] failed to sync translog
2017.11.30 08:58:56 WARN   es[o.e.indices.cluster]  [sonar-1511055210245] [[tests][2]] marking and sending shard failed due to [failed recovery]
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [tests][2] failed to recover shard
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:297) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogCorruptedException: translog corruption while reading from stream
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.ChecksummedTranslogStream.read(ChecksummedTranslogStream.java:72) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:267) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: No version type match [74]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.VersionType.fromValue(VersionType.java:307) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog$Create.readFrom(Translog.java:376) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.ChecksummedTranslogStream.read(ChecksummedTranslogStream.java:68) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
2017.11.30 08:58:56 WARN   es[o.e.c.action.shard]  [sonar-1511055210245] [tests][2] received shard failed for [tests][2], node[9r3s5guCRgKKQI-_HWik4A], [P], s[INITIALIZING], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2017-11-30T07:58:48.131Z], details[shard failure [failed recovery][IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[tests][2] failed to recover shard]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog corruption while reading from stream]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [74]]; ]]], indexUUID [zxZqVHRoSX-t0EAMHY3Fqg], reason [shard failure [failed recovery][IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[tests][2] failed to recover shard]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog corruption while reading from stream]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [74]]; ]]
```

Comment: Has the user that is running SonarQube Read/Write rights on that folder? Did SonarQube run correctly before and what did you change?

Comment: What's your version of SonarQube?

Comment: The sonar cube details : sonarqube-5.2, sonar-runner-2.4 . Yes this used to work earlier. The sonar processes are running the mysql db is running. But the logs are as above pasted and the webpage doesnt open up. No firewall issues also.

Comment: You should upgrade your system to SonarQube 5.6.7.

Answer (score 0):

The $SONAR_HOME/data/es/ was not getting deleted due to permissions but once it was deleted it fixed the problem.